# How do I make an autoclicker that goes up and down?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to make an autoclicker that clicks the up key for 10 seconds, then the down key for 10 seconds. I am using the pyautogui module for this and I am getting this error for some reason whenever I run:

```
keyUp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(2)
x = 0
times = 20 

while True:
    if x == times:
        print("Stopped Clicking")
        break

    else:
        pyautogui.keyUp(), time.sleep(10), pyautogui.keyDown()
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the pyautogui docs: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions

The `keyUp` and `keyDown` don't correspond to the Up key and the Down key, they correspond to a given key (which you have to supply as the argument) going up and down.  For example, `keyDown('space')` holds the spacebar down and leaves it down until `keyUp('space')` is called.

What I think you want is to call the `press` function on the `up` and `down` keys, something like:

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(2)

for _ in range(20):
    pyautogui.press("up")
    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.press("down")

print("Stopped Clicking")
```